# VS code - SonarLint:Simplify the expression produce invalid syntax

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

I'm getting S1125 for a code smell:

```
MyVO vo;
public boolean is() {
    return vo == null ? false : vo.is();
}
```

> Remove the unnecessary boolean literal.sonarlint(java:S1125)

But when choosing Quick Fix -> `SonarLint:Simplify the expression` it return invalid java syntax:

```
return !vo == null && vo.is();
```

Is it Sonar Lint bug ? is my vs code settings is wrong?

Obviously it should fix to:

```
return vo != null && vo.is();
```

(Using latest VS code and sonar lint plugin)

I didn't find any issue in sonar community/Jira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened a question in Sonar community https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-simplify-the-expression-wrong-syntax-on-java-s1125/62467

Which reported as [SONARJAVA-4241](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-4241)

> S1125: erroneous quick fix suggestion when negating a binary operation

and probably will be removed

> It seems that covering all the cases seems tricky. We might want to simplify and simply don't suggest a quick fix if the expression is a binary operation.